# As an unprivileged user, how can I configure sshd to allow only specified commands to be executed when it's autheticated with a password?

Tags: ssh, debian, git, sshd, git-annex

I usually log in to a SSH server (where I'm an unprivileged user) by using my public keys.  I also use authentication by a password when I use the server as a [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com)
 repository.

What I want to do is to allow only `git-annex`-related commands to be executed when sshd is autheticated with a password.  `git-annex` comes with a wrapper that's a counterpart of `git-shell` for `git`.  I know I could use `authorized_keys` to do this in other situations, but not in this particular case.

How can I do this?  The server is Debian wheezy with OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u3.

Comment: @int_541 Well, the well-known technique of restricting access via `authorized_keys` might contradict your statement, depending on what you meant by "authentication type".  (after all, this is a problem on the side of `sshd`, not of the operating system.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in front of every ssh-key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` that you want to use for git-annex exclusively (substitute *_MY_ANNEX_REPO_DIR_* and *_PATH_TO_GIT_ANNEX_SHELL_* with appropriate values):

```
command="GIT_ANNEX_SHELL_DIRECTORY=_MY_ANNEX_REPO_DIR_ _PATH_TO_GIT_ANNEX_SHELL_/git-annex-shell -c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",no-port-forwarding,no-x11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding
```

I'm currently trying to substitute Dropbox using git-annex. The settings above have been working for me for a week now. I'll update this post if I discover any problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

An unpriviledged user cannot configure sshd. You might be able to restrict your authorized_keys entries to one command. But not with a password login. 
You need root's help to change your login shell or something. If she creates a restricted shell or a chrooted jail, then this customization is possible.